# How to play a sound (wav) in Dart?

Tags: dart, audio, browser, wav, dart-html

I use a Dart script in a web page and need to play a WAV file in the browser when a certain event is triggered.  I do not use Flutter.  Instead, it is a simple DOM-interacting program.  What I’m looking for is basically the Dart counterpart of the following JavaScript:

```js
function playSound(url) {
  const audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can play a sound from a URL by writing:

```dart
import "dart:html";
final clickSound = new AudioElement("https://example.com/mysound.wav");
clickSound.play();
```

One can reuse `clickSound` for playing it as often as you need.

Comment: Note that `play` fails with an unhelpful `Uncaught` error message if it is not in code that is triggered explicitly by the browser user. In particular, you cannot use `play` in the `window.onLoad` handler.