# how can I play audio files in dart only without flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

I am learning dart now and I want to make a project to implement the concepts
that I learned.
I want to make a simple music player that works in terminal,
I want to create it in dart only without flutter.
is this possible ?
how can I play audio files in dart only without flutter?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785848/how-to-play-a-sound-wav-in-dart

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult. In Flutter you can access native code by using platform channels, and this is how all the Flutter packages do it. In pure Dart, your only way to access native code is through FFI. On Windows, the `win32` package gives you access to a huge amount of the win32 API, including the windows multimedia API ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_multimedia/ ) in particular, calls like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutopen See: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/topics/winmm-topic.html